# How to Filter from Json array and get other corresponding values using Karate

Tags: arrays, json, automation, karate

I have below json response. I want to remove where the field Value has duplicates from it using the Karate function.

```
[{"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "123"}]}},
  {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "569"}]}},
  {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "963"}]}},
  {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "963"}]}},
  {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "963"}]}},
  {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "963"}]}},
  {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "456"}]}}]
```

the result should be

```
   [{"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "123"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "569"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "963"}]}},
    {"Subject": {"Prog": [{"Type": "Identifier","Value": "456"}]}}]
```

What karate function can be used?